# How to write Prisma queryRaw Mysql iLike correctly?

Tags: prisma

I’m using Prisma at nextJs. So, I have this working query:

```
export async function findMembersByNameRaw(name: string) {
    const namesearch = '%name.toLowerCase()%'
    const memberName = await prisma.$queryRaw `SELECT
    zm.pe_id, pe.uid, pe.name, pe.gender, pe.year, zm.za_id, 
  z.za, se.sek
FROM
    zm,
    z,
    se,
    pe
WHERE
    pe.name like '%plato%'
    AND zm.people_id = pe.id 
    AND zm.zawiyah_id = z.id 
    AND z.sektor_id = se.id 
ORDER BY
    pe.id ASC
  `
  
    return memberName;
  }
```

But I need to pass variable name to that queryRaw. How should I wrote that correctly?

Refer to [PrismaDocs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access#queryraw) there is only for Postgres sample but not working in mySQL ($1 not recognize variable).

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [answer](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/3159), I can write it correctly but change to this:

```
export async function findMembersByNameRaw(name: string) {
    const namesearch = '%${name}%'
    const memberName = await prisma.$queryRaw `SELECT
    zm.pe_id, pe.uid, pe.name, pe.gender, pe.year, zm.za_id, 
  z.za, se.sek
FROM
    zm,
    z,
    se,
    pe
WHERE
    pe.name like '${namesearch}’
    AND zm.people_id = pe.id 
    AND zm.zawiyah_id = z.id 
    AND z.sektor_id = se.id 
ORDER BY
    pe.id ASC
  `
  
    return memberName;
  }
```